# How to configure `log4j` for `share-amp`

Tags: log4j, alfresco, alfresco-share

I´m working with `share-amp-archetype` trying to setup `log4j` for my module, where do I have to put `log4j.properties`?

I´ve tried in `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/{moduleId}` and it seems not work.

When in my javascript webscript controller write `logger.log("I´m here!")` nothing is logged, instead `logger.warn("I´m here!")` works fine.

In my source my files is (`src/main/amp/config/alfresco/{moduleId}`)

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts=info
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptLogger=debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger=off
```

`/src/test/resources/log4j.properties`

```
...
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts=info
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptLogger=debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger=off
...
```

Note: searching for `lo4j.properties` in `/target` I can see 5 files!!

```
target\test-classes\lo4j.properties
target\test-classes\alfresco\module\{moduleId}\lo4j.properties
target\{moduleId}-war\WEB-INF\classes\lo4j.properties
target\{moduleId}-war\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\module\share-asesorPlus\lo4j.properties
target\{moduleId}\config\alfresco\module\{moduleId}\lo4j.properties
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locations you're mentioning seem to be taken from the [Alfresco Repository extensions - logging guide](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-module-log4j.html), and not the Alfresco Share extensions section, which is why they're not working

As far as I can check/remember, Share doesn't actually have (out of the box) a context file defining extensions/modules log4j files to load.

As such, you first need to add a context file to your module with something like this in:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans>
  <bean id="log4JHierarchyInit" class="org.alfresco.repo.admin.Log4JHierarchyInit" init-method="init">
     <property name="extraLog4jUrls">
         <list>
           <value>classpath*:alfresco/module/*/log4j.properties</value>
         </list>
     </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Pop that in a suitably named context file in your amp, then you can create a log4j properties file under `config/alfresco/{moduleId}/` and have it used

(That snippet is taken from the Alfresco Repository war config, which does support module log4j files as standard. You need to bring a similar bean definition over to enable it in Share)